# How to copy on first empty row through xlwings?

Tags: python, xlwings

I want to copy data into the next available empty cell in 'S1'. For example, if data is there in cell S1 to S100 then it should copy in S101 and so on. I am using xlwings for this. This is what I am trying;

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('ABCD.xlsx')
copy_value = wb.sheets('Sheet1').range('A4').value
wb.sheets('Sheet1').range('S100').end('down').value = copy_value
```

Value of A4 will change every 5 mins since it's getting live update from the web, so I want to copy that value to the next empty cell in Col S.

Comment: This is a dumb way to solve this problem.   If you happen to get delayed, data will be lost.  Your real-time system should be appending a line to a text file.  In post-processing analysis, you can then decide how to split it up for presentation.

Comment: may be but i am very new to python and to coding is well.  Earlier i did this through excel vba macros.

Comment: Sure, but don't do that.  Excel and VBA were never designed to be real-time telemetry tools.  Go back and do it the right way.  It will make your job easier in the future.

Comment: Can you just provide me an direction? I'll be glad if you do so.